Why do the interface objects (eg cursor, cmd+tab, swiping across desktops) seem completely unaffected by lag?
Whenever my MacBook Air 2015 experiences lag, most apps and interactions are slow to respond and often send my mouse into pinwheeling.
However, the mouse cursor and trackpad shortcuts (four-finger swipe etc.) are completely unaffected like they are on a completely different OS. The mouse moves around the screen and everything is as flawless as it usually is.
Very curious as to why this is so?

I guess the real question is: what's causing your 'lag'.

The type of lag doesn't seem to matter. I've never seen the mouse lag.

I would guesstimate that the most common reasons for beachballing are the following (in no particular order):

Doing heavy calculations on the GUI thread. Well written programs should not do this, and we can probably expect to be the GUI core to be well written.

Doing heavy i/o (basically disk read/write) or waiting for network or other external resources on the GUI thread. See (1).

The system is running out of memory, and pieces of data that a program expects to be in RAM, or even pieces of the program itself, have been paged out to disk and need to be read back in again before the program can run. The GUI probably protects itself from this by not having much critical data in the first place, and locking what it has in RAM.


So to summarize: The GUI does not need much by modern computing standards, and it probably gets high-priority access to what it does need, precisely because the developers at Apple want to keep the GUI “snappy” even when everything else is bogged down.

Sorry, what's beachballing?

@GillP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel

I'd say the most common reason for beachballing is "waiting" for something else; and the pointer doesn't have to wait for much else.
